# Fill object with data

Tags: php, reflection, data-structures

I have to fill objects with data from db. I have two ideas how to do it simple and fast:

**Use of reflection** (set up child properties by row key names)

```
class Base
{
    public function SetElementByRow($row) 
    {
        foreach($row as $key=> $val)
        {
            $ref_class = new \ReflectionClass($this);
            $ref_class->getProperty($key)->setValue($val);
        }
    }
}
```

**Get propertie by string**

```
class Base
{
   protected $_row;

   public function SetElementByRow($row) 
   {
       $this->_row = $row;
   }

  public function GetPropByKey($key)
  {
      return $this->_row[$key];
  }
}
```

What do you think? Is there a better variant? What would you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of unclear what you're asking. If you start with "I have to fill objects with data from db" then the obvious answer is "so do that. Use a database interface library, and it will build them for you", job done, no work needed on your part.

If you want to know what a good class definition is for general purpose key/value storing, which is what your question follows up with: your first code block is pretty ridiculous and please never use that (why would you use reflection? If you don't know, don't use it). Your second example is a perfectly normal class.

Neither of those codeblocks have anything to do with getting data in an object from database results, though.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you're asking. You want to make an object in which its properties contain what was read from the database? Does it have to be of a specific class or just a standard object? Because PHP support direct array to object conversion, so doing the last case would be easy enough.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, whatever, data1, data2, data3 FROM mytable");

if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    $obj = (object)$row;
```